# MS Word: how to keep Word-embedded PDFs in Word-generated PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a Word documented with embedded PDFs as figures I need to convert to PDF. I was expecting the Word-generated PDF document to embed the PDF figures as is (e.g. as done by Latex) and therefore keep their original format and quality. This does not seem to be the case as Word converts the embedded PDF figures to PNGs (checked generated PDF with with Linux util `pdfimages`). Apart from Word, none of the online converters I tried so far (e.g. https://www.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/online/word-to-pdf.html) seem to be able to support this feature so I wonder if this is a Word limitation. Is there a way to ask Word not to rasterize the embedded PDFs to PNGs? Are there other software that can otherwise be used to achieve my goal?

### How to reproduce (Windows 10)

1. Download a pdf image -- e.g. https://cds.cern.ch/record/2256742/files/Figure_001.pdf
2. Open Word, then Insert > Object > Object > Create from File > Browse. Then select the previosuly downloaded PDF image. This will appear (blurry) in your Word document. This is fine as [Microsoft Office applications under Windows provide no real mechanism for placing PDF content at full quality](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/pdf-is-blurry-when-inserted-into-word-document/td-p/7029461?page=1).
3. Save/Export the PDF by either (a) File > Export > Create PDF/XPS or (b) File > Print > Microsoft Print to PDF.

The Word generated PDF will show a rasterized version of the original PDF image. In Linux you can easily check the embedded images in a PDF with [`pdfimages`](https://askubuntu.com/a/150106) in my case doing `pdfimages -all wordtopdf.pdf /tmp/out` shows the embedded imaged is `*.png`.

---

*Relevant Word options: Image size and quality is set to "Do not compress images in file" and "High fidelity".*

Answer (score -1):

As Word displays correctly the document and its embedded PDFs, a simple solution
is to **print** the document to PDF.

You could choose as the printer "Microsoft Print to PDF", or any other PDF printer
that you have installed. Choose the PDF printer whose results are good enough.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "As Word displays correctly...". Word does not naively support PDFs these are just linked and will appear blurry in the Word document. "Microsoft Print to PDF" does not embed the PDFs in the final PDF and produce comparable results to those by using the export button. What I wonder is whether it is possible to embed the already  Word-document embedded PDFs into the final generated PDF as you would get if for example you create a PDF from Latex

Comment: Seems to be a misunderstanding - I thought the PDFs were embedded in order to be displayed with the document. So why are they embedded?

Comment: I embedded images as PDFs by going into Insert > Object > Create from File. When I then do either (a) File > Export >  Create PDF/XPS or (b) File > Print >  Microsoft Print to PDF the final Word generated PDF is generated however the embedded figures in the final PDF are no longer PDFs and instead showing as PNGs

Comment: There is a third option : Menu Save As and choose the PDF format (and it's not the same as Export).

Comment: Sure but c == a (I think a is just an alias of c). In either case all yield the same results.

Comment: You might post a simple very small document to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I have just updated the question with steps on how to reproduce this.

Comment: Did it. Word 2019 - everything works correctly, object is not blurred, Save As in format PDF gives identical results. Are you using an earlier Word version?

Comment: The two (Export and Save As) are not the same.  Have you tried Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: @harrymc are you on macOS by any chance? I am using Word 2019 (Office 365) Desktop App Version 2011 (Build 13426.20404 Click-to-Run) on Windows 10.

Comment: I'm also using Office 365, but it's working for me. Is it possible that your problem is with some add-on?

Comment: Not working for me either on Windows 10 Office 365. All PDF save options are the same, embedded PDFs always get rasterized.

Comment: I played around with the pdf "image" (actually a vector-based PDF) in a Word document.  I used Acrobat PDFmaker plugin in Word to convert the file to PDF and then examined the structure - the file was definitely rasterized.  This brought back memories of a project I worked on in the '90s where I used "pdfmark" to add objects to Word files when printing (using Acrobat Distiller).  I did some more research and came up with this: Acrobat PDFmaker doesn't use Distiller anymore (which it did many years ago).  PDFmaker doesn't support pdfmark commands.  (see my next comment for additional thoughts)

Comment: The only potential approach I recommend is embedding pdfmarks where the PDF file should be included, then printing/saving to postscript (filename.ps) and then printing using Distiller.  Sounds complicated and I won't have an opportunity at this time to investigate further, but I wanted to share it as a potential solution for other experts.